# gnu linux why does command "cd xyzdir && rm -rf abcfilename" fail?

Tags: linux, command-line

```
$ touch /tmp/abcd
$ ls -l /tmp/abcd
--w--w--w- 1 dinesh users 0 Oct 16 23:49 /tmp/abcd
$ x="cd /tmp && rm -rf abcd"
$ $x
$ pwd
/tmp
$ ls -l /tmp/abcd
--w--w--w- 1 dinesh users 0 Oct 16 23:49 /tmp/abcd
```

OTOH using `x="cd /tmp; rm -rf abcd"` works as I expected. So, what's wrong with my other approach because I want to be sure I am in that directory? `$?` always returns 0.

I guess always an oppty to learn. Thanks a lot. Dinesh

```
$ uname -a
Linux test-host 3.0.93-0.5-default #1 SMP Tue Aug 27 08:17:02 UTC 2013 (925d406) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: It fails because you're incorrectly trying to put a command in a variable (they both do). Why are you doing it this way? Why aren't you just doing `cd /tmp && rm -rf abcd`?

Comment: I have a function that generates a list of directories and deletion candidates within each directory. So I execute it as in res=$( $cmd )

Comment: OK. I solved my present problem with ${parameter/#/} prepending directory name in front of every file . It however does not inform me if the directory was missing or a file name was missing. I am still curious what exactly was wrong with the `$( $cmd )` method. Thanks anyways for the pointer.

Comment: This [offsite resource](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) describes it (quotes and redirections work similarly to `;` and `&&` for this purpose).

Answer (score 0):

We get the idea if we turn on trace output (`0>` is the prompt).

```
0>set -x
0>$x
+ cd /tmp '&&' rm -rf abcd
```

We see that `&& rm -rf abcd` are just passed as extra arguments to the `cd` command. Obviously the parsing of `&&` as a command list operator only takes place before parameter expansion, no more after `$x` has been substituted. Oddly, `cd` doesn't complain about the extra arguments - try:

```
cd . dumb and dumber
```

Logically

```
eval $x
```

works as desired.

> OTOH using `x="cd /tmp; rm -rf abcd"` works as I expected.

You must be mistaken here.

```
0>$x
+ cd '/tmp;' rm -rf abcd
bash: cd: /tmp;: No such file or directory
```

Just as `&&`, `;` is not parsed as a control operator here, but simply as the last character of the directory name `/tmp;` - consequently yielding an error.